# Sort File for Duplicates if greater than a certain number

Tags: awk, command-line, sort

I have a `file.log` file with data that may or may not occur more than once.

```
a
b
c
a
d
b
a
a
a
a
b
z
d
e
f
e
```

I am currently using `sort file.log | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 10` to sort them by the amount of duplicates found in the file, but I am getting the top 10 occurrences. So for example, if one character reappears 5 times in the file, it says `5` and the character corresponding to it.

How can I output the lines to get the characters with more than a certain number of occurrences/duplicates found in the file? For example to get only the characters that occur more than 10 times. And preferably a way to define how many of those characters to output, for example only 5 results of characters that have 10 or more duplicates.

Comment: Try `awk`, you can set up conditions on the fields.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I tried something like ```awk ' { tot[$0]++ } END { for (i in tot) print tot[i],i } ' file.log | sort``` but I don't know how to get it to start at an index of N wherer N is the number of times the character has occurred (# of duplicates).

Comment: But you don't have to replace the old command, keep on building the pipe after it. `file.log | uniq -c | sort -rn` gives you a list of "ocurrences, character". Your awk will only need a condition on $1 (with the range you want). Eventually, you might readd the `head` to get the top ones.

Answer (score 1):

Using your given input, if you want to find which characters appear greater than or equal to three times: keep a count and output the line on  the third time it is seen

```
$ awk '++count[$0] == 3' file
a
b
```

Pipe that to `head` to limit the output. This clearly does not sort by number of occurrances. To do that, using GNU awk:

```
gawk -v limit=3 '
    { ++count[$0] }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
        n = 0
        for (line in count) {
            if (n == limit) break
            print count[line], line
            ++n
        }
    }
' file
```

outputs

```
6 a
3 b
2 d
```

Ref https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sort file.log | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{if($1 >= 10 && $1 <= 20){{print $1, $2}}}'
```

Comment: Since your answer is not entirely self evident (especially the `awk` at the end), it would be a benefit for the user in the question if you could explain what you're doing. It looks to me as if you would throw away any characters that occur more than 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the start of your original pipeline and then `awk` to filter those results:

```
sort file.log | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '$1 >= 10' | head -n 5
```

The `awk` at the end prints only those lines that corresponds to counts greater or equal to 10.  The `head` at the *very* end limits the overall result to a maximum of five lines.

You may do a bit more in `awk` though:

```
awk '{ c[$0]++ } END { for (w in c) if (c[w] >= 10) print c[w], w }' file.log |
sort -nr | head -n 5
```

This does the counting and the weeding out of low-count lines in `awk` first, then gives you the top five results of that with `sort` and `head`.

The counting is done by incrementing an element in an associative array `c`, where  the current line of input is used as a key.

The `END` block (which is triggered after reading the last line from `file.log`), iterates over all the keys in `c`, and if the key corresponds to a count larger than or equal to 10, the count is printed along with the line that has that count.